# Visual Studio 2010 freezes when debugging x64 application

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, windows-7, 64-bit

Recently, my coworker and I upgraded our development environment to Win7 x64 with VS2010 Pro. Our application is specifically targeted at x64 platform.

The problem we are encountering is during debugging, when attempting to step through the code (F10), at least 50% of the time VS will simply lock up the application being debugged. The IDE has the appearance of having pressed F5, but the application is not responsive and we have to force stop the application.

Our application is a Client (GUI) and a Server that communicate through .NET remoting.

This is starting to directly affect our productivity, so if anyone has any ideas what may be causing this, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

There is an outside chance that it might be the debug symbols loading. Check the status bar I think it tells you when the symbols are loading.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the debug symbols are all loaded at startup...pretty sure, not positive.  The odd part is, it will sometimes step through a dozen lines of code with no problem, sometimes it will happen on the first line.

Comment: Try and switch off the loading of symbols and see if that does help ? I assume that this only happens if you are stepping not if you just run it in debug mode ?

Comment: Correct...stepping only. I will try that tomorrow.

Comment: It wasn't the symbols.  I did find it though, someone had added a background timer to "ping" the client from the server.  Whenever this timer would elapse and query the client while the server was in debug mode (step through), it would cause something to break and give the issues I experienced.  Refactoring that timer (refactor = eliminate!) fixed the problems.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Well spotted that must have been hard to pickup!

Answer (score 0):

This may be a moot point, but have you installed the VS 2010 service pack 1?

There are various bugfixes related to debuggers included.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/983509

Comment: We have not installed VS2010 SP1 due to the intelisense bug when SQL Administration Studio is installed.  See my below comment for what our problem was.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. it turned out that a higher level program had a different run-time library (multi-threaded debug dll), while my app was simply a multi-threaded debug.  Once I converted mine to a multi-threaded debug dll, the freeze stopped happening.